# How to replace mutliple values in a list in c#?

Tags: c#, replace

If I have a list of 100 integers, how would I assign the values at index 20 to 50 to a different set of values in a list of length 31 without the use of loops? Coming from python this is very easy to do without looping but am unsure if it is possible to do in c#.

Comment: When you say "without loops", are you allowed to use something that uses loops, like LINQ?

Comment: It's logically impossible to do this without loops and without hard-coding the indexes. Please define what you actually want

Comment: How would you do it in Python? We could show you something functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LINQ, which is "without using loops in my code", you could:

```
hundredInts.Take(19).Concat(thirtyoneInts).Concat(hundredInts.Skip(50));
```

(and if you want it back as a list or array etc, the relevant ToXXX call on the end of it)

Or perhaps:

```
hundredInts.Select((n, i) => (i < 20 || i > 50) ? n : thirtyOneInts[i-20])
```

Or built in stuff:

```
hundredInts.RemoveRange(20, 31).InsertRange(20, thirtyOneInts);
```

Comment: I'd really refrain from telling someone that doesn't know c# that LINQ is a solution for this. People get the wrong idea and look at me like I was crazy when I explain them that linq doesn't do magic and it *does* use loops

Comment: Hah., yeah.. Gonna be a lot of typing to do it looplessly with a list, I fear!

Comment: A lot of CTRL+C, CTRL+V you mean haha

Comment: Yea, I think I'd use sublime and textpastry

Answer (score 3):

There's no trivial way to do so with Lists. However, this is easily done with arrays using [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int64_System_Array_System_Int64_System_Int64_):

```
var destIndex = 20;
Array.Copy(sourceArray, 0, destArray, destIndex, sourceArray.Length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can use loops under the hood, you can create an extension method, like

```
public static class MyExtensions{
    public static void SetRange<T>(this List<T> source, IEnumerable<T> newValues, int startIndex){
        var newValuesList = newValues.ToArray();
        int numberOfElements = Math.Min(source.Count - startIndex, newValues.Count());
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
            source[i + startIndex] = newValuesList[i];
        }
    }
}
```

And use like the following:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();   
var list2 = Enumerable.Range(1000, 31).ToList();
list.SetRange(list2, 20);
```

This will replace the values in `list`, starting at index 20, to the values of `list2`. You can also modify the extension method to add another parameter to estipulate the number of elements that you will take from `list2`, like the following:

```
public static void SetRange<T>(this List<T> source, IEnumerable<T> newValues, int startIndex, int numberOfElements){
        var newValuesList = newValues.ToArray();
        numberOfElements = Math.Min(numberOfElements, source.Count - startIndex);
        numberOfElements = Math.Min(numberOfElements, newValues.Count());
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
            source[i + startIndex] = newValuesList[i];
        }
    }
```

You should probably also add a validation if `startIndex` and numberOfElements are greater than or equal to 0.